# Pygame mask collisions not detected even with offsets at zero

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, collision, mask

I am writing a game using pygame. A skier object moves left and right on the x axis, whilst tree objects move up the screen on the y axis. From outside the extracted code, the Tree class method collide is called passing the object tree and skier (i.e. `Tree.collide(tree,skier)`). I have modified the collide method so that it prints the x and y offsets and whether the collision test is met (i.e. is `ret_mask` none). Having limited the underlying program to one skier and one tree with the same x-co-ordinates, I see the tree pass right through the skier generating a printed `offset_x` and `offset_y` of zero, but is still get a `ret_mask` of `None` even with the tree passing completely through the skier and off up the screen on the y axis. Looking at some older code, I tried adding `.convert()` when loading the PNGs and also setting `colorkey(white)` - as indicated by the comments. However, this made no difference.

Any help on why I am not getting collisions greatly appreciated!

```py
# Load Image PNGs
white=(255, 255, 255) #added definition of white
SKIER=pygame.image.load(os.path.join('assets','skier_img.png')).convert() #added .convert() to end
SKIER.set_colorkey(white) #added line
TREE=pygame.image.load(os.path.join('assets','tree_img.png')).convert() #added .convert() to end
SKIER.set_colorkey(white) #added line


# Define Object Classes
class Sprite:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y
        self.img=None

class Skier(Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super().__init__(x,y)
        self.img=SKIER
        self.mask=pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)

class Tree(Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        super().__init__(x,y)
        self.img=TREE
        self.mask=pygame.mask.from_surface(self.img)

    def move(self,vel):
        self.y-=vel

    def collide(obj1,obj2):
        offset_x=obj2.x-obj1.x
        offset_y=obj2.y-obj1.y
        ret_mask=obj1.mask.overlap(obj2.mask,(offset_x,offset_y))
        if (obj1.mask.overlap(obj2.mask,(offset_x,offset_y)) != None):
            print('Collision Detected!')
        else:
            print(f'offset_x is {offset_x} and offset_y is {offset_y} and mask output is {ret_mask}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry everyone! I worked it out.
Actually, the steps I took with the .convert() method and the set_colorkey(white) DID WORK.
It is just that I had an error in my code due to doing a copy and paste: I set the colorkey on the SKIER twice rather than doing the TREE.
Also, huge thanks to Rabbid76 who reformatted the code in my question properly - sorry about that I posted in a hurry.
Overall a zero score in covering myself in glory....